# Интервал между однотипными запросами

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

Столкнулся с проблемой большого количества POST запросов на контроллер от клиента.
Запросы вида:

```
$(auth_form).submit(function () {
        const uri = '/enter/auth';
        const data = $(auth_form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            data: data,
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            type: "POST",

            beforeSend: function () {
                NProgress.start();
            },

            complete: function () {
                NProgress.done();
                NProgress.remove();
            }
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#password').val("");
                switch (data.type) {
                    case 'OK':
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.location = "/cp";
                        }, 2000);
                        new PNotify({
                            title: 'Success',
                            text: data.message,
                            type: 'success',
                            hide: false
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'ERROR':
                        new PNotify({
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: data.message,
                            type: 'error',
                            hide: false
                        });
                        break;
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
```

Сервер написан на spring-boot.
Собственно говоря вопрос - как задать интервал между такими запросами на стороне сервера? Пытался найти хоть какую-либо информацию по этому поводу - 0 информации. 
Так же имеются два фильтра CSRF

```
public static class StatelessCSRFFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    public static final String X_CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
    static final String CSRF_TOKEN_COOKIE = "CSRF-TOKEN";
    private static final int EXPIRE = 0;
    private final RequestMatcher requireCsrfProtectionMatcher = new DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher();
    private final AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (requireCsrfProtectionMatcher.matches(request)) {
            final String csrfTokenValue = request.getHeader(X_CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER);
            final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

            String csrfCookieValue = null;
            if (cookies != null) {
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                    if (cookie.getName().equals(CSRF_TOKEN_COOKIE)) {
                        csrfCookieValue = cookie.getValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (csrfTokenValue == null || !csrfTokenValue.equals(csrfCookieValue)) {
                accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response, new AccessDeniedException("Missing or non-matching CSRF-token"));
                log.warn("Missing/bad CSRF-TOKEN while CSRF is enabled for request {}", request.getRequestURI());
                return;
            }
        }

        invalidate(response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void invalidate(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(CSRF_TOKEN_COOKIE, "");
        cookie.setMaxAge(EXPIRE);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    public class DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
        private final Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return !allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches();
        }
    }
}

public static class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String LOCALHOST_DEV = "https://87.98.180.70:8443";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, LOCALHOST_DEV);
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");

        if (request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD) != null && HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equals(request.getMethod())) {
            // CORS "pre-flight" request
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE + ", " + StatelessCSRFFilter.X_CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER);
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, "1");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

возможно можно сюда реализацию интервала запихнуть, но как это конкретно сделать не представляю. Метод на стороне клиента оборачиванием функции в `setInteval(function() { .... }, 5000); или trottling` не предлагать, интересуют решения только на стороне сервера

Answer (score 0):

Ну если прям в лоб решать задачу можно написать свой javax.servlet.Filter, который будет перехватывать абсолютно все запросы на сервер, ну а на нужных Вам будет делать Tread.sleep(), например. Каким-то магическим параметром вряд-ли это делается.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку, но было найдено другое решение - https://github.com/weddini/spring-boot оказывается есть реализация не только на стороне клиента